# Design of a basic Java Push Service

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

At the moment, I have a server operating on a simple wait for request basis. The server will wait for client input, and reply with the appropriate response and then repeat this process. The client also operates on this basis, sending a request to the server and waiting for a response. Eventually I will change this so there will be queues for incoming and outgoing messages on both ends, so waiting for a particular response is no longer an issue. I now wish to integrate basic push technology into my server. I am unsure on how to do this and wish to ask about the basic design behind this.

Here is a basic rundown of the problem. When the server receives a connection, it spawns a thread (the connection) which writes and reads from and to a pseudo-database (just a static class). All threads write and read from and to this database. With the new push technology, when data is updated in the database, that data is supposed to be pushed out to all clients.

My question is when data is updated due to a single thread on the server, what is the best practice/design patterns used to communicate from said thread to every other thread. I am looking for the basic design without any helper libraries.

Comment: This question probably is too broad for stackoverflow it's a question about good design, whereas stackoverflow is more a forum for technical "how to..." questions.

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question.  What you want is, when one client updates the database, other clients are notified; but what you _asked_ was about threads.  You seem to equate clients with threads.  That might be a bad idea.  "Pushing data" to a client makes sense, but pushing data to a thread... not so much.  I define threads by what they wait for, not by what they do.  (e.g., this thread waits for messages from a particular client, that thread waits for arbitrary background tasks.)  A thread that pushes data to client X need not be the same thread that waits for/responds to client X.